# How do I exclude columns from a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table, and want to exclude some set of columns. For example,

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:2, b = 2:3, c = 3:4, d = 4:5)
dt[ , .(b, c)]
```

Gives me the second and third column, b and c. How do I instead EXCLUDE columns b and c. Coming from the data.frame world, I would expect something like the following:

```
dt[ , -.(b, c)]
```

or, maybe

```
dt[ , !.(b, c)]
```

But neithr of these work. I know I can use

```
dt[ , -c(2:3), with = FALSE]
```

but this just (as I understand it) casts the data.table as a data.frame and then uses the standard operations. I would like to avoid this, since it is a) kind of cheating, an b) gives up the speed boosts available in data.table. I reviewed the data.table FAQ, and the vignette, and cannot seem to find anything.

(I know this is all very simplistic, and I could just select the other two columns. However, this is a microcosm of a much, MUCH bigger data.table I am working with.)

Comment: You can use `setdiff` i.e. `dt[, setdiff(names(dt), c("b", "c")), with = FALSE]`  `with = FALSE` is needed for subsetting columns

Comment: Kind of strange that no one below posted `dt[ , -c("b", "c"), with=FALSE]` or `dt[ , !c("b", "c"), with=FALSE]`. Anyways, you are being vague about what you mean by "exclude". Dropping those columns from the table is very different from making a new table that doesn't have those columns. I don't think `with = FALSE` "casts the data.table as a data.frame", but if you really want to do that, you probably want `setDF`.

Comment: I already know how to do dt[ , -c("b", "c"), with=FALSE], which I mentioned in the original post. To be clear, I am under the impression the 'with = FALSE' argument slows down data.tables considerably, because they are then treated as data.frames. So, I was trying to avoid that. Also, by 'exclude', yes, I meant assigning the current DT to a new DT without those columns, rather than removing them in place. (I can work with either, though. The distinction doesn't really affect what I am attempting to do.)

Comment: You mentioned `-c(2:3)` which works but isn't names; and `-.(b,c)` which does not work; not `-c("b","c")`, so I wasn't sure you knew it. Anyways, to the extent that `with=FALSE` is slow, it is because you are copying a bunch of data when constructing the new DT. In contrast, removing in place (by assigning NULL) is basically instantaneous, so if either way works for you and speed is a concern, you should use the latter. Besides, it will use up less memory. The result of either operation is still a data.table, so I think you are mistaken about treatment as data.frames.

Comment: In the recent versions something like `dt[, !c("b", "c")]` worked for me which doesn't need the 'FALSE' argument.

Answer (score 25):

Also, in case you would not wish to change the data.table, but merely return the columns except some columns, you can do:

```
dt[,.SD, .SDcols = !c('b', 'c')]
```

which returns the required result of:

```
   a d
1: 1 4
2: 2 5
```

while dt remains unchanged:

```
> dt
   a b c d
1: 1 2 3 4
2: 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: This is the only answer I see that fulfills OP's criteria (not using `with = FALSE`), without altering the original data.table ( setting columns to 'NULL')

Answer (score 9):

We can use `setdiff`

```
dt[, setdiff(names(dt), c("b", "c")), with = FALSE]
```

or we can assign to `NULL` (as in the other answer) but in a single step

```
dt[, c("b", "c") := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
  dt[ , b := NULL][ , c := NULL]
```

or you can use a list of columns to be removed:

```
xx <- c("b","c") # vector of columns you DON'T want

# subset
  dt <- dt[, !xx, with = FALSE]
```

Comment: Or `dt[ , \`:=\`(b=NULL, c=NULL)]`

Comment: there is no reason to use `dt <- dt[, !xx, with = FALSE]`, if you assign results to same variable, it is better to make it by reference

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer because it removes the column as opposed to merely excluding it. That is, when you execute this, `b` and `c` will no longer be columns. You should instead use `dt[, setdiff(names(dt), c("b", "c")), with = FALSE]`

Comment: @CoreyLevinson , the output of your response is identical to mine.

Comment: @rafa.pereira If you look at `dt` after executing your statement that assigns `NULL` to the columns, the columns `b` and `c` are missing because they have been deleted. However, using the other method, the columns remain. The original question asks to *exclude* the columns, not to remove them entirely.

Comment: When I compare the results of both methods using `identical(a,b)` and get result `T`.

Comment: you don't understand what corey is saying. there is a difference between deleting by reference, that is, deleting them from the original frame, and changing the output so that the output doesn't have the columns. This is a very basic difference in the data.table syntax, check out a basic tutorial if this is hard to grasp :)

Answer (score 4):

you can always just do:

```
dt[ , -c("b", "c")]
```

although this uses the data.fame sintax and as the problems you describe, particularly it seems to be much slower on large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `set`:

```
set(dt,, c("b", "c"), NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using R and the data.table package. I am trying to add the index number of the columns you wish to EXCLUDE from your data.table object within c function, prefixed with a minus sign "-".

With respect to the sample of code you have shared,

```
    dt <- dt[,c(-<index of column "a">, -<index of column "b">)]
```

Note: " index of column "a" " and " index of column "b" " and the angular brackets < and > should be ignored, it should be replaced by the index number of the column you wish to exclude.

Personally, I would not recommend you, to use the index of the columns for deselecting columns as it is not a good practice, this was told by the co-author of data.table package, Arunkumar Srinivasan,in a DataCamp course on data.table.

```
    dt <- dt[,-c(<"name of column to be deselected">, <"name of column deselected">)]
```

Note: *name of column to be deselected* and the angular brackets < and > should be ignored, it should be replaced by the name number of the column you wish to exclude.

Comment: This doesn't seem useful for the case where the columns to exclude are potentially long vector of column names or columns to drop are not known before hand